# Data annotations not detected when views are based on view models (and not models entities)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I refactor my code in order to respect the view model pattern. I also used the AutoMapper. Now, I have a question related to 'Required' and 'DisplayName' annotations. Originally I set these annotations on the model. I thought this was the best place to be. But now that I use a viewModel on my views I'm wondering

**Do I have to move 'DisplayName' and 'Required' annotations from my model to my view model classes?**

I noticed that my annotations on my models are no more detected in my views (now based on view models).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in fact, annotations are one of the reasons to have view models, because then you don't have to pollute your domain classes with annotations, that are only meaningful in particular view.

It's tempting to have everything in one place, to be really DRY, but domain model may be not interested at all in whatever is going in your views. It's not his responsibility. It's common fight between *don't repeat yourself* and *single responsibility*, you have to find the sweet spot between them:)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes.

Reflection is used on the type of your model (declared in the view) to figure out what attributes need to be given to their respective mark-up.

Comment: Bartosz: ok, so if I have 3 different views based on user infos, I will duplicate some 'Required' annotations, right? Wel always told "don't duplicate things", but in this cas we have no choice?

Comment: If they are common properties, you can create a base class with these properties and attributes and subclass them. If, however, you are asking for exactly the same information the views can share the same view model type. The point of the MVVM pattern is to de-couple your views from your domain models, it does not necessarily require a view model per view.

Comment: Well, whetever there is DRY('don't repeat yourself') there is also that 'Single responsibility' thing. Domain models with view annotations are DRY, but break the SR. Always up to you to find the sweet spot:)

Comment: View models are not necessarily a repetition of the domain model objects... they are an abstraction of the view's state.